# cgroups CPU quota vs system load metric

Tags: linux, cgroups, load

I'm wondering about if and how cgroups affects system load metric. Let's assume I'm running CPU-heavy process within cgroups with config:

```
cpu.cfs_quota_us = 50000
cpu.cfs_period_us = 100000
```

So basically, it can run for 50 ms in each 100 ms period. It also means that the process can (and will?) be switched between suspended and active states 10 times in 1 s. How much will this process increase the load metric? 1 - because it's the same process? 10 - because it was scheduled 10 times? Something else?

Answer (score 1):

The system load metric is the average number of *runnable* processes, that is, processes which would run if only they had a CPU available. Your hypothetical process will increase the system load between 0 and 0.5: the maximum is 0.5 because you allow it to run only 50% of the time, and the minimum is zero because it may be waiting for I/O or a semaphore, may be blocked by a signal etc.